# Java applications with Windows 7 - are there compatibility concerns?

Tags: java, swing, windows-7

with some fuzz around Windows 7, does somebody have experiences with Java compatibility with Windows 7? Should this be a concern or do the programs probably work ok?

I'd be especially interested if somebody has experiences with Swing applications?

The versions available seem to be beta versions so they won't provide perfect basis for evaluation but some.

br, Touko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using various Java apps on my Win 7 x64 box just fine and never had any problems. Even some of my oldt poorly coded swing apps have worked without issues.

For the most part, Win 7 is Vista in new clothing. Shouldn't have much issues because of that.

Answer (score 3):

Updating info related to the question:

According to [Supported System Configurations for Java SE 6 and Java For Business 6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/install/system-configurations.html)
,

```
Windows 7 support was introduced in 1.6.0_14
```

From [Java SE 6 Update 14 Release Notes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u14.html) changes:

```
6821003 hotspot runtime_system Update hotspot windows os_win32 for windows 7
```

From [Java SE 6 Update 18 Release Notes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u18.html):

```
For 6u18, support has been added for the following system configurations:
    * Windows 7 support is now available
```

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest concern is having the right Java runtime installed.  WHen that is out of the way you can expect properly written Swing programs to work identically.

(With proper I refer to not having hardcoded button sizes or similar)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problem of swing application in windows7 there are stated below:

1. JCheckBoxMenuItem will not show image

   ```
    JCheckBoxMenuItem(Icon,Text,boolean);//Icon will not displayed
   ```

you can refer the https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7122141.

2. Focus issues. Sometimes escape won't work

Comment: UAC issues,we need to very keen before playing with the %ProgramFiles%.Windows7 security  Folder structure is good ,it depends how we make our code

Answer (score 0):

The problem I have with my Swing application on Windows 7 (and presumably Vista - haven't tried it), is that the Java Runtime indicates to Windows that it is UAC-aware, while my application that runs in the JVM actually isn't.  As a result, if someone installs it into the traditional location (e.g. C:\Program Files\MyApp), the application fails because it cannot write configuration data or error log files to its installation directory.  Because I use some third-party libraries that write their own files to the current (i.e. install) directory, and I've got many more important things to do than dig into those libraries just to make their error reporting and configuration storage UAC-aware, I took the path of least resistance and changed my default install directory to C:\MyApp.  I realize that this is a regression back to the old DOS days where people ended up with myriad application directories in C:\, but it's not my fault that Windows' method of implementing UAC Virtualization for legacy applications doesn't work for Java apps.