# Dialog box gets all covered in black

Tags: java, dialog

I was running a program (a Java exercise in our class) and the other one tinyumbrella for my iphone. when i try to run these programs, their dialog boxes are covered in pure black that i cant really read them. I have asked my professor bout this but he said it was the first time he encountered it yet. the buttons are the only ones left seen.

here's how it looks. http://thericofranco.wordpress.com/

Comment: This seems to be a problem that is locally caused by the Operating system. Did you try restarting the machine? Also, go to www.java.com and download the latest software

Comment: I have tried restarting and my Java is up to date. but still the problem remains. I have also installed the appropriate ATI Catalyst driver but there's no difference observed.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without any code, but for me looks like

- you are either actually painting it black
- something is blocking the paint process

Throw all the code out that is not needed for reproducing the problem and post what is left. Of course it is rather likely that you'll find the problem yourself in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Are using a ATI radeon video card?

Check out [java paint problem - black components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743635/java-paint-problem-black-components)

This s a known issue with the catalyst driver